# weird characters being appended to requests

Tags: apache-2.2, php, php5

I am running apache2 with php5, wordpress and getting this weird thing where symbols will append to the end of a jqeury request and then quotes on the other pictures. If I clear my cookies it fixes it but tends to come back every day.

Here is a video showing the weird error: https://mediacru.sh/BCDAN-9vfqMB/direct

Edit: it seems to be caused by wordpress and having me logged in as an admin. So now to figure out why that is....

Edit 2: Has nothing to do with any plugins, I deactivated them all and the issue still occurs.

Edit 3: Seems its something with php or apache, the characters are showing on all my websites now. The admin thing with wordpress must of been something to do with having old cache.

Comment: %22 is an encoded " (quote) character. There is some malformed link in the HTML, and so instead of requesting absolute urls from your external cdn, its ending up hitting your main webserver

Answer (score 0):

Solved by removing php5 and having it install libapache2-mod-php5